# In what ways have Buddhists responded to the apparent impossibility of saving all sentient beings?

Tags: bodhisattva-vows

In what ways have Buddhists responded to the apparent impossibility of saving all sentient beings?

Do they claim that it isn't impossible, or only need be partially achieved, or that not all Buddha's took this vow, or what?

Comment: No Buddha takes such a vow according to Theravada Buddhism. Are you expecting an answer from Mahayana?

Comment: @SankhaKulathantille would be great to answer with that. i don't mind

Comment: in my answer i would guess that as bodhi is a function of bodhicitta the understanding of te vow changes with enlightenment. but i can't find any sourses that say this explicitly, so...

Answer (score 2):

From the Mahayana viewpoint, the mind of enlightenment is the wish to achieve buddhahood in order to benefit all sentient beings. It is true we also often say "to set them in enlightenment" as well.

The omniscient mind of a buddha gives birth to the teachings of the buddha in that it causes him to teach us the Dharma. We say that the teachings of the buddha emanate from his omniscient mind (the wisdom truth body part of the dharmakaya). In a way, he teaches all of us but some do not have the ears to listen to him. This is merely an analogy. The meaning is that not all sentient beings have the karma to listen to the Buddha dharma but his enlightened deeds (in particular his teachings) pervade all sentient beings, just like the rays of the sun illuminate indiscriminately. However, the deeds of a buddha do not engage with all sentient beings, they are **capable** of doing so.

In his *Commentary to Maitreya/Asanga's Great Vehicle Treatise on the Sublime Continuum* (mahayanottaratantra-ratnagotravibhanga) Gyaltsab Je says:

> These three can be illustrated: meditating on the path of utilizing
>   the basic element results in the attainment of the dharmakaya of a
>   perfect buddha whose enlightened deeds emanate and pervade to all
>   sentient beings. These enlightened deeds of the dharmakaya are capable
>   of engaging with sentient beings and exist exclusively for the mind
>   streams of sentient beings. Because of this it is said that all
>   sentient beings possess tathagata essence. This is similar in meaning
>   to the Abhisamayalamkara when it says, "Because enlightened deeds are
>   vast, it said that the buddha is all pervasive."

And

> Illustrating the teachings of conventional and ultimate truth with
>   similes gives further explanation of the term "emanate" in the line,
>   "The perfect buddha body emanates. " This is because "dharmakaya
>   emanates" means "dharmakaya pervades," which in turn refers to being
>   pervaded by enlightened deeds, and enlightened deeds engage with all
>   sentient beings by way of the speech of the tathagatas teaching the
>   dharma to various disciples. The capability of the enlightened deeds
>   to engage with sentient beings is always present and this is the
>   meaning of "pervaded by the dharmakaya.

Additionally, according to Mahayana tenets, the continuum of a buddha is not severed. His enlightened deeds will not stop as long as one being remains in samsara.

Comment: From the beginning of-the Agama-sutra is supposed to be the oldest sutra-Buddhist sutra, but even in Agama-sutra this kind of thought is there. [It] says, Shujo muhen-"Sentient beings are numberless. I vow to save them." Wikipedia: "In Mahayana Buddhism, the bodhisattva vows to work for the relief and liberation (nirvana) of all sentient beings as long as samsara persists."

Comment: If the goal is merely to  "attain complete enlightenment for the sake/benefit of all sentient beings", this goal is no different to Hinayana Buddhism because the silent sage does not kill, steal, hurt, etc, therefore the silent sage has attained the state of benefiting all sentiment beings merely due to their impossibility of harming others.

Comment: @Dhammadhatu Except merely not harming others is not the meaning of "benefiting sentient beings" according to Mahayana. As I explained above, the meaning of "benefiting all sentient beings" according to Mahayana is "being capable of engaging with sentient beings by way of emanating enlightened deeds out of the omniscient mind [part of the dharmakaya]." One must therefore achieve the omniscient mind.

Answer (score 2):

This is Hui Neng's (the Sixth Zen Patriarch) interpretation of the first of the Bodhisatta's Four Vows:

> Learned Audience, all of us have now declared that we vow to deliver an infinite number of sentient beings; but what does that mean? It does not mean that I, Hui Neng, am going to deliver them.  And who are these sentient beings within our mind? They are the delusive mind, the deceitful mind, the evil mind, and such like minds-all these are sentient beings.

From 'The Platform Sutra': http://zen.thetao.info/read/platform.htm

Answer (score 1):

The short answer?

You actually save all the beings in your heart. The hell within. Your demons within of anger, craving, delusion. When they are saved you are left with enlightenment.